# Error when installing Microsoft Sql Server 2019, cannot find the microsoft OLE DB Driver

Tags: sql-server, installation, driver

[Error given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkdWu.png)

I am having trouble installing Microsoft SQL server 19 Express (I tired dev aswell, it does the same thing). It keeps giving me the error:

> Error Description: An installation package for the product Microsoft
> OLE DB Driver for SQL server cannot be found, Try installing again
> using a valid copy of the installation pacakage 'msoledbsql.msi'

So what I tried was redownloading it from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/download-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15 and running the .msi file. It runs fine and gives no errors but it still does not fix the issue. It still will not find the file and without it I cannot install the program. Or am I using the wrong driver for it? The other thing I have tried is when clicking on the .msi it gives me the option to remove or repair.  I've done both as well (reinstalling after remove) but it still gives me the error. I'm very very lost at this point. Could anyone possibly help?

Comment: Have a look at links in the comments on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71756617/sql-server-2019-developer-edition-download-failed

Comment: @squillman That link now points to a SO question that was removed, so it no longer works (at least for me)

Comment: @ReversedEngineer Indeed...  There were a couple of related questions from the time that question was asked and they are all deleted now.  If I remember the conversation correctly, it boiled down to a bug in the installer.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I managed to fix it, first, you need to go to programs and features and uninstall the "Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server" that is there and then let the installer install the new one

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me as well. I removed all OLE and ODBC drivers, then it worked.

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm. I think I got this error because I installed SSMS first and then installed when trying to install `SQL2019-SSEI-Eval` I got this error.

Comment: but my concern is why remove new version to replace with old one? isnt that a bug and should be reported to microsoft? Whichever software installed the latest version must have done it for a reason.

Comment: This also fixed the same issue when installing SQL Server 2022 Developer Edition.

Answer (score 1):

Simply uninstall existing ole db then run your sql server setup afresh

Answer (score 0):

remove all OLE and ODBC drivers and re run the setup

Answer (score 0):

I deleted ALL "Microsoft ODBC Driver"s and "Microsoft ODBC Driver"s and then the new install of SQL Server worked.  After installing it, I had 2 new "OBCD Driver"s and one "OLD DB Driver for SQL Server" in Programs and Features. And note, after the install, I now had about 25 different "Microsoft SQL Server"s installed,from "2008" to "2022".

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar error when trying to install SQL Server 2022 developer edition. When I tried to install OLEDB driver, It gave me error that it needs VC++ redistributable. I tried to install X64 version VC++ redistributable (https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x64.exe) but was still getting same error. Finally, this error was fixed when I installed 32 bit version using https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x86.exe